# Why does Dummit and Foote specify the identity of a group $G$ as $1$?

Tags: group-theory, notation, definition

A group need not necessarily be composed of integers.

Why does Dummit and Foote specify the identity as $1$?

Consider $G = \{\text{Jim}, \text{Lara}, \text{Kan}\}$ s.t. the identity of $G$ is $\text{Lara}$.

Comment: It’s an abstract $1$, not a literal $1$.

Comment: they denote it by the symbol "1"

Comment: also, if you want to be technical, the real number "1" is different from the rational number "1", which are both different from the integer "1"

Comment: symbol overloading is common in mathematics, part of doing math is learning to context switch depending on the particular area of math you're currently working in.

Comment: @mathworker21 Don't forget the natural $1$ which is different yet again.  At the end of the spectrum of common uses of $1$, we could add the complex number $1$.

Comment: wait, why was this question downvoted? I think it's a fine question

Comment: It could just as well have been the symbol $0$ for an abelian (*i.e.*, commutative) group.

Comment: Technically $\,1\,$ is a symbol that *names* a specific element of the underlying set of the structure. Symbols can be any mathematical object - including elements of the underlying set (in your example it is not). The role played by these names will be clarified when one studies model theory (for example see W. Hodges textbook, Chapter 1: *Naming of parts*)

Comment: @mathworker21 Tell me about it...I was demoralized at the downvote.

Comment: Historically it's been written as 1 early. For instance in Jordan's 1870 "Traité des substitutions" it's called "unit" and written 1. Some authors have noticed that this may be confusing and proposed $e$, which is now also used. Sometimes $1_G$ or $e_G$ is useful to specify the group $G$. Also the wording (identity/unit/ neutral element) is not universal. "Identity" can be inconvenient, notably to distinguish between the identity map of $G$, and the neutral element of $G$, which are distinct things. "Identity" comes from the fact that initially groups were defined as permutation groups.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the same reason we write the group operation $\cdot$ or $+$, it is because we are abstracting the ideas of our normal number systems into groups/rings/fields. It makes sense because we are redefining "$1$" to be simply the multiplicative identity, and then the intuition of how multiplicative identites work in $\mathbb R$  or $\mathbb Q$ actually gives good intuition for the general group setting.

I will add two things: not all concepts carry over, for example (even though Lang seems to do it) thinking about a group operation as $+$ when the operation isn't abelian usually breaks intuition, so we use $\cdot$ generally (because we can easily think of a classical non-communative multiplication: matrix multiplication). Secondly, for (finitely generated) abelian groups, it actually turns out that every group looks exactly like a bunch of copies of $\mathbb  Z$ 
(called the free part) together with copies of the integers modulo some set of numbers (called the torsion part).

Comment: Your last sentence isn't really true - what about $\mathcal{Q}=(\mathbb{Q}, +)$? For *finitely generated* abelian groups it's correct, but there are a lot of other abelian groups. (Yes, $\mathcal{Q}$ is a union of lots of "$\mathbb{Z}$-pieces" - each rational generates a "$\mathbb{Z}$-piece" - but the way they fit together is highly nontrivial, so it's not really helpful to describe it as "a bunch of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$.")

Comment: Right, of course, the theorem is called "the classification of finitely generated abelian groups" haha I just forgot to write the condition, I'll edit. I'm interested by what you said in the second part, though - I always think of $\mathbb Q$ as the fraction field of a finitely generated group, but can you actually get it from some semi-direct product or a categorical infinite product construction?

Comment: @JuanSebastianLozano $\mathbf{Q}$ has the property that any two nontrivial subgroups nontrivially intersect, hence is not a semidirect product. On the other hand, like any group, it's directed union (filtering inductive limit of injections) of its finitely generated subgroups; here it can be described as inductive limit of a sequence of infinite cyclic groups (where the $n$-th homomorphism is, say, multiplication by $n$).

Answer (score 3):

Just to give a different viewpoint to Juan.

We have not developed enough symbols to give every distinct concept its own symbol.  Some reuse is necessary.  In general, you need to watch the context to know the meaning of the symbol.  Even within a particular context, you need to check what the author means by it.

You might be more familiar with the identity of a group being denoted by $e$ but this is also commonly used for the base of natural logarithms and frequently just for an arbitrary number.  If you are reading a paper on group theory then $e$ is probably the group identity.  If the paper is on calculus then $e$ is more likely to be the base of natural logarithms.

As mentioned in comments, $1$ in the Natural numbers, the Integers, the Rational numbers, the Real numbers, and the Complex numbers is not technically the same thing but few people get confused or upset by that.

Using $1$ for the identity of a group in which the operation is denoted as multiplication is attractive.  I am surprised that is not more common.

$1$ is typically used for the multiplicative identity of a field or a ring.  Also $2$ is commonly used for $1 + 1$, $3$ for $2 + 1$ etc.  More care is needed with these since, in an arbitrary ring or field, they are not all necessarily non-zero.

$\pi$ is probably the most consistently used symbol but even it is sometimes used for things very different from the famous number.

Comment: Yes, and still $\pi$ is used in statistics as a parameter to be estimated, and in number theory as the prime counting function.

Comment: And sometimes for a permutation.  I have met some people who expected that every Greek letter had a single fixed special meaning e.g. $\Sigma$.  Some are even surprised to learn that for the Greeks, $\pi$ is just a letter with a sound similar to our letter $p$.